# Generic parameter if raw defaults to Object

Tags: java, generics, java-7

I'm working on a Java 7 based project. I wanted to introduce a generic parameter on one of the classes, so that I can slowly eliminate the class casts required to make the code work.

Let's introduce a class, that is similar to the one I'm working on:

```
public class A {
   public List<B> getB() { ... }
}
```

`B` has lots of child classes, which when used, need to be casted, which is not ideal obviously. The modification I'd like to make is like this:

```
public class A<T extends B> {
    public List<T> getB() {...}
}
```

This can eliminate the casting required in some cases. However, `A` is used in a big part of the project, which makes it not too efficient to go through and rewrite every case it's used.

I hoped, that using the raw `A` class will make it so that `getB()` will return a type of `B`. The reality is that if used raw, `getB()` will return a type of `Object` instead. Is it some Java 7 related behavior, or am I overlooking something? Is there a way to make `getB()` return a type of `B` when `A` is raw? I didn't seem to come across this issue in Java 8, though I haven't really worked on a project this poorly structured either.

Edit: In the comments, I was requested for concrete code example, where the issue occurs. Assuming the above classes (edited slightly to better fit my actual scenario):

```
A a = new A();
for(B b: a.getB()) { // Compiler error, because `getB()` returns a list of `Object`s instead of `B`s.
    ...
}

A<B> a = new A<B>();
for(B b: a.getB()) { // Everything is fine here obviously
    ...
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't be `Object`, [it would be `B`](https://ideone.com/RDE919), since that's the erasure of `T`. But generally, no, there is no shortcut here: you need to suck it up and add all of the type parameters everywhere.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting an instance of type `Object` instead of `B`? I tried and I'm getting type `B`. I used Java 8, though.

Comment: Can you provide us with a small use case? I mean, an example of where it is returning an `Object` instead of `B`.

Comment: edited my original post

Comment: *Is it some Java 7 related behavior*: no.*Is there a way to make getB() return a type of B when A is raw?* no. Just don't use raw types. Do the right thing, and refactor the code properly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: Even though the question is probably good, you have a weird way of structuring it. You probably mean that once you introduce a generic parameter to an _existing_ class, all the _callers_ will use raw type of the class, thus no type safety, as they will now all return `Object`, right? If so, yhis is not specific to java-7, at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your intention seems to be that, assuming a `class C extends B`, you could have an `A<C>` whose `getB()` method returns a `List<C>`. But if you allow old code to treat the method of the same object as returning `List<B>`, it could call `getB().add(new B())` on it, which would subvert the entire type safety.

Of course, it might be that the old code never does that, perhaps, the list is even immutable, but the compiler’s type system doesn’t know.

Since you have to touch the code anyway, to benefit from the new generic type, you can extend the class, e.g.

```
public class A {
    public List<B> getB() { ... }
}

public class ExtendedA<T extends B> extends A {
    public List<B> getB() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(getT());
    }
    public List<T> getT() { ... }
}
```

You can only get the benefit of the new type parameter `T` for new or updated code, when an `ExtendedA` is created and consistently passed through the entire code path. But at any point where the `ExtendedA` is passed to old code, it continues to work as before, as long as the old code obeys the restrictions mentioned above. The code must not attempt to add `B` instances when not knowing the actual type parameter. But in this solution, the restriction is enforced at runtime by the `unmodifiableList` wrapper, so the generic type safety is retained, which is the reason why the signature of the wrapper method allows the type transition from `List<T>` to `List<B>`.

The best migration strategy would be to adapt all creation sites of `A`s as soon as possible, as then, the `A` class could become abstract, just serving as an interface for old code whereas `ExtendedA` is the actual type safe API and implementation for all new and updated code.